# adjusting RMarkdown Themes

Tags: themes, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown Document i want to embed in a shiny app based on the `prettydoc` engine. I have seen a [tutorial](https://yixuan.cos.name/prettydoc/cayman.html) about using the `cayman` theme for my document. The problem is i want to change the gradient in the header to be `sunkist` based on the gradient sheet [here](https://uigradients.com/#Amethyst). Does anyone know how to achieve this. Is it a setting in the YAML

In the example supplied you type something like

```
---
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: Harry Potter
date: July 31, 2016
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
---
```

An Additional information on the cayman theme can be found [here](https://github.com/jasonlong/cayman-theme)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `theme` in YAML will not achieve what you intend to do. These themes are prebuilt and unless one of them already have the `Sunskit` gradient set, the outcome won't be what you desire.

An alternate approach would be to make the change in the stylesheet of the theme. For example:- In the `cayman` theme, you could open the `cayman.css` and this to the bottom.

```
.page-header {
  background-color: #F2994A;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A);
}
```

This would change the gradient in the header.

Comment: Hi @ghosh. I added the line at the end of the page in CSS but it didnt seem to change anything in the header when i hit `knit` Is there an option i must set or should i remove the previous `.page-header ` section

Comment: @JohnSmith I edited the snippet it should work now. Here is a link to screenshot - http://jmp.sh/v/kSn8i8kfpVfbFnKDhjvH. If not, you could also try editing the existing styles.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to change. Are you running your markdown document in Rstudio or do you open it in a browser?  Thank you again for your help. It is a very valuable learning experience

Comment: I edit it in the browser. Can you confirm if your stylesheet is changing? Do you see the styles you added when you debug in the browser?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. When i open it in IE i get the following `<section class="page-header">
<h1 class="title toc-ignore project-name">Just Another Demo</h1>
<h4 class="author project-author">John Smith</h4>
<h4 class="date project-date">11 May 2017</h4>
</section>`

Comment: it opens it as a text file but our changes are present